# How can I see custom components in QtDesigner?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-designer

I am developing a Qt Quick 2 Application using QML to define my components.
I would like to create a folder in the project where to put common components (such as customized buttons or labels), and specifically I would like to see this components in the Qt Designer view, in order to be able to drag-drop those elements while designing new views.

I see that the Qt Designer view only shows to you the components located at the same path of the qml that you are currently developing, **but I haven't found a way to display components located in other paths**.

The project tree should be something like this:

- **RootFolder**

  - CommonComponents
  - Views

where the qmls developed in the Views folder will use components defined in the CommonComponents folder.

Does anyone know how to configure the project or the QtDesigner in order to achieve this goal?
Thanks

Comment: How do you import the qml files in different directories ? Shouldn't be a `import "CommonComponents"` be sufficient ?

Comment: Importing components in that way is enough to use them by manually editing the .ui.qml, but the component is still not shown in the designer view library for drag&drop or in the design preview neither.

Comment: Ah, now I see what you mean. For that you would need to install them as plugins in the installation directory of your Qt, I believe. Having them in your project folder won't do.

Comment: Delivering a plugin is a solution that I am discussing with the customer who requested this application, but he is not so happy of doing that :(

Comment: I am not sure if it works, but if you want it only for a certain project and it is purely QML with no C++, maybe it is already sufficient to set `QML_IMPORT_PATH`  in the .pro or .qmlproject files

Comment: I have just tried, but it's not working. I tried to put a qmldir file in the CommonComponents folder for listing files, but it's pointless as well